# Pipe screen buffer to another command?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, pipe

I can't seem to find anything on this so, is there a way to pipe everything from a screen window into another command.  I have a server running in screen (not the best idea, but the only way for the server atm), and want to parse the output (while it is running, is it possible to take everything printed to that detached screen into another command?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Consider restarting the server and piping its output through `tee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to log output of a running screen session, do the following:

1. Attach to the session.
2. Press your <kbd>Prefix</kbd> key (<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> on an unchanged setup), then <kbd>:</kbd>, enter `logfile <filename>`.
3. Again <kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd>, enter `logfile flush <interval in seconds>`.
4. <kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd>, enter `log on`.

`screen` will now log all output to the file `<filename>`, every `<interval>` seconds. You can `tail -f` that file to process the output.

You can skip steps 2 to 4 and just press <kbd>Prefix</kbd>, then <kbd>H</kbd>. The defaults will be `screenlog.n` for `<filename>` and 10 seconds for `<interval>`.

Note that the file can grow quite large if you have a lot of output to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
$ screen -d -m sh -c "/path/to/my/exec | tee output.log"
```

Comment: Would this output as the server is running? Or only after the server is restarted?  Sorry, can't really test on a live server (restarts aren't great on a game server), and don't want to duplicate the environment if I don't need to.